# Clojure: finding out if a collection is seq-able

Tags: clojure, clojureclr

So there's list?, seq?, vector?, map? and so on to determine what type of collection the argument is.

What's a good way of telling the difference between

- a map (i.e. something that contains key-value pairs)
- a collection (i.e. something that contains values)
- a non collection value like a string.

Is there a better way than

```
#(or (seq? %) (list? %) etc)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<s>using `seq?` is about as concise and clean as it gets.</s>

clojure.contrib.core defines:

```
seqable?
    function
    Usage: (seqable? x)
    Returns true if (seq x) will succeed, false otherwise.
```

http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/core-api.html

it does what you proposed with one big `or` statement of

- already a seq
- an instance of clojure.lang.Seqable
- nil
- instance of Iterable
- an array
- a string
- instance of java.util.Map

Comment: In the current version of Clojure (1.5) seqable? is currently living in clojure.core.incubator (repo @ https://github.com/clojure/core.incubator)

Answer (score 6):

Let's not forget about [`sequential?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sequential_q):

```
user=> (sequential? [])
true
user=> (sequential? '())
true
user=> (sequential? {:a 1})
false
user=> (sequential? "asdf")
false
```

Answer (score 4):

The function `seq` right now does only this:

```
(. clojure.lang.RT (seq coll))
```

In `RT.java` in the latest version of Clojure, you'll find:

```
static public ISeq seq(Object coll){
    if(coll instanceof ASeq)
        return (ASeq) coll;
    else if(coll instanceof LazySeq)
        return ((LazySeq) coll).seq();
    else
        return seqFrom(coll);
}

static ISeq seqFrom(Object coll){
    if(coll instanceof Seqable)
        return ((Seqable) coll).seq();
    else if(coll == null)
        return null;
    else if(coll instanceof Iterable)
        return IteratorSeq.create(((Iterable) coll).iterator());
    else if(coll.getClass().isArray())
        return ArraySeq.createFromObject(coll);
    else if(coll instanceof CharSequence)
        return StringSeq.create((CharSequence) coll);
    else if(coll instanceof Map)
        return seq(((Map) coll).entrySet());
    else {
        Class c = coll.getClass();
        Class sc = c.getSuperclass();
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Don't know how to create ISeq from: " + c.getName());
    }
}
```

An `ASeq` or a `LazySeq` is already a seq.  A `Seqable` is something that knows how to return a seq of itself.

That leaves things like Java core classes, which should be seqable but which Clojure can't alter to add a `seq` method.  Those are currently hard-coded into this list.  I wouldn't be surprised if the implementation changed someday, maybe using protocols to extend the Java core classes instead?

Answer (score 0):

All seqables implement clojure.lang.Seqable marker:

```clj
(instance? clojure.lang.Seqable x)
```

Clojure 1.9 provides [`seqable?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/seqable_q)